# A finite union of convex bounded open subsets of $S^{n}$ has finitely generated cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, general-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $V_{1},...,V_{n}\subset S^{d}$ be convex, bounded, open subsets of $S^{d}$. Show that $H^{d-1}(\cup_{i=1}^{n} V_{i})$ is finitely generated.

According to a solution here [Complement of a finite union of convex sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224287/complement-of-a-finite-union-of-convex-sets#new-answer?newreg=dc5d2b3fd2a54a77b8e4c5b55649aba0), it should be solvable 'by an easy induction on $n$ using Mayer-Vietoris sequences.' When I try applying the Meyer-Vietoris sequence to the pair $\left(\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}V_{i} \ , \ V_{n}\right)$ I get the exact sequence
$\cdots \rightarrow H^{d-2}(\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}V_{i})\times H^{d-2}(V_{n}) \rightarrow H^{d-2}\left((\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}V_{i})\cap V_{n}\right)\rightarrow H^{d-1}(\cup_{i=1}^{n} V_{i})\rightarrow H^{d-1}(\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}V_{i})\times H^{d-1}(V_{n}) \rightarrow H^{d-1}\left((\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}V_{i})\cap V_{n}\right)\rightarrow H^{d}(\cup_{i=1}^{n} V_{i})\rightarrow \cdots$

This seems promising, but feel like I need to better understand $H^{d-2}\left((\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}V_{i})\cap V_{n}\right)$ and $H^{d-1}\left((\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}V_{i})\cap V_{n}\right)$ to proceed. Is there something I am missing? And is this even the correct Meyer-Vietoris sequence to consider?

Comment: $(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} V_i) \cap V_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} (V_i \cap V_n)$, and $V_i \cap V_n$ is convex as it is the intersection of convex sets, which has finitely generated cohomology by your inductive hypothesis.

Comment: This is more appropriate for math stack exchange.